# What is the best location for Cypress tests when testing multiple modules independently

Tags: automated-tests, components, cypress, directory-structure

I'm writing automation tests for a multi-module system and I want to be able to run each features' spec files independently to allow the developer working on a certain feature to develop its tests simultaneously.

Additionally, I have an automation module to run all the tests as part of our release cycle.

1. Where should the spec files be? within each feature module or should the automation module contain all of the spec files?
2. If the spec files are part of the feature module, how should the automation module consume them?

Answer (score -1):

It's usually not a good idea to mix the app. code with Cypress and .spec files because they should be two separate projects. Obviously, it is not a rule, the requirements of each project are different.

If you start with the idea of creating tests for each feature in the app, they will quickly become difficult to maintain. In most cases, you will need to create tests only for important elements of the application.

Comment: "you will need to create tests only for important elements of the application" - 
Totally disagree. Ideally every aspect of the product should be automatically tested

Comment: Ideally, yes, but if you work on a big project it's not achievable. Yes, you can create automated tests for every section, but in a big project those sections will be modified and along with them, the tests will have to be modified.